# Setting "sync" icons in file explorer

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, microsoft-file-explorer

Is it possible to set green checkmarks on files in windows file explorer using C#? To mark a file/folder "synced" or not.

Basically how Dropbox/OwnCloud/Subversion does it.

Been trying to find information regarding this but it doesn't seem to be a built-in file attribute, from what I've been able to find?

Is it possible to **add** an icon to the existing file icons?

Sort of like this:

[image]

Comment: These are handled by *Icon Overlay Handlers* which are a type of shell name space extensions.  Because they must be implemented as *in-process* COM objects creating them in managed code is strongly discouraged.

Comment: As @AlexK. said, It is [Icon Overlay Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-implement-icon-overlay-handlers) but for packaged applications, there is a [desktop4:DesktopIconOverlayHandlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop4-desktopiconoverlayhandlers) element while it is not used by [CloudMirror](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/44d192fd7ec6f2422b7d023891c5f805ada2c811/Samples/CloudMirror/CloudMirrorPackage/Package.appxmanifest#L48).

Comment: Great stuff, thanks for the info! Will need to research more about this, but now I at least have a name for the "method" to lookup :)

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexK. said, it is [Icon Overlay Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-implement-icon-overlay-handlers) for normal files but [for cloud based placeholder files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop3-cloudfiles), there is a [desktop4:DesktopIconOverlayHandlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop4-desktopiconoverlayhandlers) element. Also see [the question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1518657/implementing-the-ishelliconoverlayidentifier-inter) for some exploration.